# Task for pid iOS gui

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cydia, tweak

I'm writing an iosopendev tweak with an graphical user interface to do some task for pid code.

The app itself has an control, postint, prerm file to get root access/privileges.

Postint:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "/Applications/test.app/"

# process origin binary
mv test test_
chown root.wheel test_
chmod +s        test_

cont=`cat <<"EOF"
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(dirname "$0")
exec "${dir}"/test_ "$@"
EOF
`
# create new fake binary
echo -e "$cont" > test
chown root.wheel  test
chmod +x          test

#The RESPRING script after Install
declare -a cydia
cydia=($CYDIA)

if [[ $1 == install || $1 == upgrade ]]; then
if [[ ${CYDIA+@} ]]; then
eval "echo 'finish:restart' >&${cydia[0]}"
fi
fi
```

exit

Prerm:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f "/Applications/test.app/test_"
```

Are there any ways to sign the app and get task_for_pid access?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using theos?

Comment: Yes - the latest revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sign the app when you make it, not when you install it.

1. Install `ldid` to sign your binaries. If you are using macOS with Homebrew, install it with:

   ```
   brew install ldid
   ```

   Check http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup#Setting_Up_Dependencies for other platforms.
2. Create an entitlement file (`ent.plist`):

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>get-task-allow</key>
       <true/>
       <key>task_for_pid-allow</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
3. If using theos, put `ent.plist` next to the Makefile, then add this line to your Makefile (change `test` to the name of the target):

   ```
   test_CODESIGN_FLAGS = -Sent.plist
   ```

   If using Xcode, put `ent.plist` inside ${PROJECT_DIR}, then set the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS build setting of your target to `ent.plist`.

   > [image]

Comment: It's an xcode project, theres no Makefile available there. Thanks anyways